# Which control/element to use in android application for conversation thread

Tags: android, xml, android-activity

I need to show conversation in my android application like this :

```
Student Message: Hi, this is test message
Instructor's Reply: Thanks for test message
---------------
Student Message: Hi, this is test message
Instructor's Reply: Thanks for test message
-----------------
Student Message: Hi, this is test message
Instructor's Reply: Thanks for test message
```

Can you please tell which control should i use for this. TextView or anything else ??

Any help would be highly appreciated !!

Thanks..
Anjum

Comment: listview of textview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use list view.. as you get replay or send message from/to server keep adding list item to list view

list view example

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

chatting view example 
http://javapapers.com/android/android-chat-bubble/

Answer (score 1):

You'll want a [ListView](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html) and you'll want to set it to transcript mode.

That being said, know that implementing a ListView is not trivial. There is an old Google I/O talk on Youtube by Romain Guy and Adam Powell that talks about implementing [ListViews](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70).